# Coronavirus crisis: why Microsoft & Amazon more resisting compared to Google?

Tags: stock-markets, stock-analysis

just checking some stock prices:

- Google: 1530$ before the crises. now at 1100$ --> -28%
- Amazon: 2170$ before the crises. now at 1910$ --> -12%
- Microsoft: 190$ before the crises. now at 152$ --> -20%

My  assumption is that Amazon is more resisting because delivery services are very popular during these days. However, cannot see why Microsoft is more resilient compared to Google.

Answer (score 2):

There may not be one definitive reason, but I'll throw out one possibility.  Many employees are working form home these days, so cloud services like Teams, Skype, and Office are seeing increased usage since the pandemic began.  Teams alone saw a [700% increase](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/update-2-on-microsoft-cloud-services-continuity/) in usage during a one-month period in Italy.

Amazon is probably also benefiting from web services, but I would presume that online shopping is helping more than that.

Comment: You should also note that Google cloud and apps have had outages thanks to their scaling issues. This will have exaggerated the effect.

Comment: Also most of Google's revenue is advertising revenue.... Companies that are currently in terrible shape are obviously not advertising and thus google suffers greatly